# Symfony intersection entity with 3 entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have 3 entities, `domain`, `slideshow` and `slideshow_container`. Basically, in our old system and database I created an intersection entity (/table) called `Slideshow_slideshow_containers`.

Basically, a `slideshow_container` can contain zero or one `slideshow`, and `slideshow` can be in multiple `slideshow_container`, however, my intersection entity before had a column `domain`, as per domain you can specify which `slideshow` is in which `slideshow_container`

I know I can make an intersection entity, which I've done now:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SlideshowSlideshowContainerRepository")
 */
class SlideshowSlideshowContainer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\SlideshowContainer", inversedBy="slideshowSlideshowContainers")
     */
    private $slideshowContainer;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Slideshow", inversedBy="slideshowSlideshowContainers")
     */
    private $slideshow;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Domain", inversedBy="slideshowSlideshowContainers")
     */
    private $domain;
```

Is there a way to solve this without the extra class (which for normal many-to-many relations isn't necessary).

Comment: nope, as soon as your relation has an attribute of any kind (or a link to a third entity) you need a dedicated entity/class to handle that. sorry ;o/

Comment: @Jakumi Oh okay, that sucks but makes sense